# Why is python ignoring my formatter in the console?

Tags: python, logging, outputstream

am working on a Python app that implements  logger features

Here is my code which is taken form the official [site](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html):

```
import logging

#create logger
logger = logging.getLogger("simple_example")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

#create console handler and set level to debug
fh = logging.RotatingFileHandler(MyFile, etc)
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

#create formatter
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - 
   %(message)s")
#add formatter to fh
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
#add fh to logger
logger.addHandler(fh)

#"application" code
logger.debug("debug message")
logger.info("info message")
logger.warn("warn message")
logger.error("error message")
logger.critical("critical message")
```

and here is the output in the File: **which is perfect**

> 2005-03-19 15:10:26,618 - simple_example - DEBUG - debug message
>
> 2005-03-19 15:10:26,620 - simple_example - INFO - info message
>
> 2005-03-19 15:10:26,695 - simple_example - WARNING - warn message
>
> 2005-03-19 15:10:26,697 - simple_example - ERROR - error message
>
> 2005-03-19 15:10:26,773 - simple_example - CRITICAL - critical message

**but** here is the output in the terminal:

> DEBUG: debug message
>
> INFO: info message
>
> WARNING: warn message
>
> ERROR: error message
>
> CRITICAL: critical message

that drives me crazy since i can not get to see the timestamp in the console...

I have tried too creating another handler:

```
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

and the adding it to logger...

but the only thing I get is that the logger in printing twice every msg in the console... one perfectly ok and the wrong one as I explained at begin

Comment: `fh.setFormatter` doesn't set the formatter to `logger`, so what's the issue?

Comment: that is the issue, I want that fh either log in the console with the format I set or dont log at all in the console but just in file...

Comment: Seems you copied the first example on that page, not the *Multiple handlers and formatters* one that probably gets you closer to what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A initialization in the basic configuration on the logger is necessary for that:

```
logging.basicConfig(streamä0sys.stdout, level=logging.INFO, format=myFormat)
```

where

```
myFormat= "%(asctime)-15s %(clientip)s %(user)-8s %(message)s"
```

Comment: Its often not a good idea to use basicConfig. For example I am using a Flask app, and Flask also uses logging. When I want to add custom information to the logs it will cause the logger inside Flask to fail. See [Thomas Lehoux answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42028365/540725) for a logger-specific solution

Answer (score 5):

The console output can be adjusted separately using `StreamHandler`, for which you have to add the formatter as well:

```
#create console handler and set level to debug
fh = logging.RotatingFileHandler(MyFile, etc)
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

#create formatter
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - 
   %(message)s")
#add formatter to fh
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
#add fh to logger
logger.addHandler(fh)

ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(ch)
```

Comment: I have only one handler (the rotatingFileHandler) which other do you mean?

Comment: the StreamHandler one.

Comment: I ended up here because python still ignores the formatter even after I set it on the StreamHandler

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I use for logging in a file and in the console:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s\t%(message)s', datefmt='%m-%d %H:%M', filename=logfile, filemode='a')
# define a Handler which writes INFO messages or higher to the sys.stderr
console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# set a format which is simpler for console use
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s\t%(message)s')
# tell the handler to use this format
console.setFormatter(formatter)
# add the handler to the root logger
logging.getLogger('').addHandler(console)
# Now, we can log to the root logger, or any other logger. First the root...
logging.info('LOGGING PATH: %s', logfile)
```

Then you can set the same output for both the file and the console.